# combined backend calls in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I m trying to make a backend call in order to get some data and do the second call from it. Backend calls working perfectly but the only problem is the promises. I cant get the data from first promise so i can make the second call from it..
Any ideas where am i doing wrong ?

```
login() {
        if (this.formLogin.valid) {
            var data;
            this.userService.performRequestLoginToBackend(this.formLogin.value.username, this.formLogin.value.password).then(response => {
               data = response;
                //    this.userStore.dispatch({type: 'USER_LOGIN', data: this.userData});
            }, (response) => {
                if (response.status < 500) {
                    console.warn('Login failed!');
                } else {
                    console.error('Internal Server Error');
                }
            });
             this.userService.performSecondRequestLogin(data).then(response2 => {

                    this.parsePromise(response2);
                }, (response2) => {
                    if (response2.status < 500) {
                        console.warn('Login failed!');
                    } else {
                        console.error('Internal Server Error');
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

the second way what i have tried :

```
login() {
        if (this.formLogin.valid) {

            this.userService.performRequestLoginToBackend(this.formLogin.value.username, this.formLogin.value.password).then(response => {
              this.userService.performSecondRequestLogin(response).then(response2 => {

                    this.parsePromise(response2);

                }, (response2) => {
                    if (response2.status < 500) {
                        console.warn('Login failed!');
                    } else {
                        console.error('Internal Server Error');
                    }
                });
                //    this.userStore.dispatch({type: 'USER_LOGIN', data: this.userData});
            }, (response) => {
                if (response.status < 500) {
                    console.warn('Login failed!');
                } else {
                    console.error('Internal Server Error');
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

UPDATE: Still doesnt work...

```
  login() {
        if (this.formLogin.valid) {

            this.userService.performRequestLoginToBackend(this.formLogin.value.username, this.formLogin.value.password).then(response => {
                 return this.userService.performSecondRequestLogin(response);
                //    this.userStore.dispatch({type: 'USER_LOGIN', data: this.userData});
            }, (response) => {
                if (response.status < 500) {
                    console.warn('Login failed!');
                } else {
                    console.error('Internal Server Error');
                }
            }).then(response => {

                  this.parsePromise(response);

            },(response) => {
                if (response.status < 500) {
                    console.warn('Login failed!');
                } else {
                    console.error('Internal Server Error');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Backend call for first call

```
     performRequestLoginToBackend(_username: string, _password: string) {

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('xxx').subscribe(data => {
      });

    });
    return promise;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following to chain promise. In this case, the final `then` callback, the response is the response of the second call.

```
this.userService.performRequestLoginToBackend(
  this.formLogin.value.username,
  this.formLogin.value.password).then(response => {
           data = response;
          return this.userService.performSecondRequestLogin(data); // <-----
        }, (response) => {
            if (response.status < 500) {
                console.warn('Login failed!');
            } else {
                console.error('Internal Server Error');
            }
        }).then(response => {
          (...)
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "I cant get the data from first promise"? Thanks!

Comment: With your latest update, you need to flatten that promise chain more. So after `return this.userService...`, close the `.then` and start a new one...

Comment: my performSecondRequestLogin method not being called.. i need to give the promise to this method, so this method makes the second backend call, and finally i parse the last promise for username and password

Comment: Could give you me more details of the implement of these methods? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think @Thierry Templier's answer is almost there but you need to flatten the promise chain correctly:

```
this.userService.performRequestLoginToBackend(
      this.formLogin.value.username,
      this.formLogin.value.password).then((response) => {

              return this.userService.performSecondRequestLogin(response); // <-----

          })
          // Flattened properly here, assuming performSecondRequestLogin 
          // returns a promise
          .then((response) => {
                if (response.status < 500) {
                    console.warn('Login failed!');
                } else {
                    console.error('Internal Server Error');
                }
           })
           // Catch for good measure!
           .catch((error)=>{...});
```